# WPF bind window min height to the height of two grid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm using C# with .NET 4 on MSVC 2012 under Win7.

I have a window with a grid control of 3 rows on it in a WPF application project.

Here are my row definitions:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="145"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The top row has a menu bar in it. The middle row has a few controls in it. The bottom row sizes with the window and its contents aren't relevant. I would like to "bind" the minimum height of my window to the combined height of the first 2 rows so that the window can be minimized to the point where they are the only ones visible.

I think I can use the "Custom Expression" option in the visual designer but I'm not sure. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set SizeToContent Property of Window equal to WidthAndHeight instead of Binding.I hope this will help.

Comment: I'm looking to set the minimum size.

Comment: Your Window will be automatically set to minWidth of your controls.